# Finding resouces by namespace

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

I am using `kubectl`. How to find dangling resources by the namespace?

For example, I have some namespaces.

```
kubectl get ingress --all-namespaces |awk '{print $1}'
```

That is supposed to be deleted. If I find those namespaces on GKE there is no result returned.

So why `kubectl` are me showing those namespaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find dangling resources on a particular namespace with the following command:

```
kubectl api-resources --verbs=list --namespaced -o name \
  | xargs -n 1 kubectl get --show-kind --ignore-not-found -n <namespace>
```

If you need to force the namespace deletion, you can do so by removing the [Finalizer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/finalizers/):

1.

```
kubectl get namespace <namespace> -o json > <namespace>.json
```

2. 

```
kubectl replace --raw "/api/v1/namespaces/<namespace>/finalize" -f ./<namespace>.json
```